# How not to confuse the use of words also, as well, too?

Tags: meaning

Also, as well and too are adverbs and mean ‘in addition’.
How do you know when to use which word?  What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

Tough question.  The 3 expressions - "also", "as well" and "too" are interchangeable in the following context and, therefore, your preference on which to use.

```
I have a large dog. I have a small dog, too.
I have a large dog. I have a small dog as well.
I have a large dog. I have a small dog also.
```

The following most likely in response to someone saying that they have a small dog:

```
I too have a small dog.
I also have a small dog.
I as well have a small dog. (Although this is probably not common)
```

However, they are typically not interchangeable in other contexts.  Example:

```
I had too much to eat.  
Not equal to:  I had also much to eat.
Not equal to:  I had as well much to eat.
```

Comment: Looking at [the Merriam-Webster dictionary's entry for "too"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/too), it is clear that the first two sets of examples use definition 1 ("besides, also"), while "too much to eat" uses definition 2a ("to an excessive degree; excessively") or 2b ("to such a degree as to be regrettable").